# How to deal with "compaction overlapped" error after constructing Apache IoTDB cluster in V1.0.0?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I use Apache IoTDB V1.0.0 to create a new IoTDB cluster. When the project is running, I inserted data into IoTDB and check the log of IoTDB, and find the following error: [pool-46-IoTDB-Compaction-6] ERROR o.a.i.d.e.c.CompactionUtils:281 - root.test Device is overlapped between [file_name]. I cannot understand this error message, seems like it is about compacting data? But I did not set any new compaction method. Anyone know how to explain this?

I also checked the issues on Github, but still cannot find answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this bug is caused by cluster settings in V1.0 and is already been fixed in newer versions. You can try to upgrade Apache IoTDB to V1.1 and see if this problem has been solved.